# CORS Support for Bulk API

Tags: authentication, bulk-api

According to [this documentation](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_api_bulk_cors.htm), the bulk API should now support CORS.  However, I'm not finding that to be the case.

My the preflight request (OPTIONS) is failing with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><error
   xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
 <exceptionCode>InvalidSessionId</exceptionCode>
 <exceptionMessage>Unable to find session id</exceptionMessage>
</error>
```

Here is what the OPTION request looks like:

```
curl 'https://cs12-api.salesforce.com/services/async/40/job' -X OPTIONS -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-sfdc-session' --compressed
```

*I've tried every combination of endpoint url I can think of. Always same result*

Which makes no sense, because I'm pretty sure the token should not be required for the [pre-flighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests).

I can confirm that I properly have CORS setup because I am querying the Rest API and Custom Rest Endpoints right before this request fails.

HERE is a visual-force page to reproduce the error yourself.  You need to add CORS Whitelist for Visualforce subdomain and endpoint URLS in javascript:

```
<apex:page >
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const __ACCESSTOKEN__ = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
    function doRest(){
        console.log('running rest');
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'https://na46.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Account',
          success: function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            $(".rest").text( JSON.stringify(data) );
          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown)
              alert('ERROR: Check Console for details');
          },
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + __ACCESSTOKEN__
          },
          dataType: 'json',
        });
    }

    function doBulk(){
        console.log('running bulk');
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'https://na46.salesforce.com/services/async/39/job',
          data: {
              "object":"account",
              "operation": "insert",
              "contentType": "JSON"
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            $(".bulk").text( JSON.stringify(data) );
          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown)
              alert('ERROR: Check Console for details');
          },          
          headers: {
            'X-SFDC-Session': __ACCESSTOKEN__
          },
          dataType: 'json',
        });
    }



    </script>

    <button onclick="doRest();">
        Run Rest Request
    </button>

    <button onclick="doBulk();">
        Run Bulk Request
    </button>
    <hr/>
    <h2>
    Rest Result
    </h2>  
    <pre class="rest">

    </pre>
    <h2>
        Bulk Result
    </h2>
    <pre class="bulk">

    </pre>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: If I send the option request to the bulk API 2.0 endpoint it does return 200

Answer (score 0):

After many weeks salesforce finally confirmed it's a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=unable-to-use-cors-with-bulk-api-1-0&Id=a1p3A000000mD6L).